# Can I use rowmode: 'array' in combination with named parameters?

Tags: pg-promise

Is it possible to have `rowMode: 'array'` and named parameters at the same time? Right now, with the code below, I'm getting `syntax error at or near "$"`

`` db.query({
      text: `
        select task_nr, commitment
        from surveys
        where email = $<email> and id = $<id>
        order by task_nr
      `,
      values: {email: email, id: id},
      rowMode: 'array',
    }) ``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible, because `rowMode` is strictly part of the [Parameterized Query](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/ParameterizedQuery.html), which by definition forwards query formatting to the driver->server where such thing as Named Parameters does not exist.

Unfortunately, if you really need to use `rowMode`, you can only use the basic `$1, $2...` variable formatting as supported by the server.

Strictly speaking, `rowMode` is not that valuable, it is fairly easy to reformat the data, and then just use [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) default formatting with all its nice formatting features.

Comment: In most cases I use named queries, but rowMode is valuable to me in a few specific cases. In some of my queries, the result set is pushed straight into a charting component, and using non-row-mode means that pg-promise changes the values into objects only to have me change them right back to rows.